# VBA - Excel Append Every Active Row With File Name

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA so bear with me.  I would like to append in the last cell of each active row the filename. So for example Row/Column A1, B1, C1, and D1 are populated I would like to add the filename to cell E1.  The filename should only be appended to active rows.  I have played around with different iterations without much luck.  Below is what I have so far and the logic is clearly incorrect.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Sub InsertFilename()

```
Dim Count1 As Long
Count1 = 1
Dim ColumnE As String
ColumnE = "E1"


While Cells(Count1, 1) <> ""
Range(ColumnE).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=MID(CELL(""filename""),SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))+1, SEARCH(""]"",CELL(""filename""))-SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))-1)"
ColumnE = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)).Select
Count1 = Count1 + 1
Wend
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code iterates from the first row to the last, and it finds the last column in each row by imitating the CTRL+LEFT from the edge of the sheet.

It does not assume that all the rows have the same number of columns

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Sub InsertFileName()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim i as Long
  LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  For i=1 To LastRow
    LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i,LastColumn+1)="=CELL(""filename"")"
  Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks for taking the time and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution.  Add your values for `fileName` to be appended and the start row `stRow` of your data.

```
Sub InsertFilename()
Dim stRow As Long, endRow As Long, endCol As Long, c As Long
Dim fileName As String

fileName = "C:\Data\somefile.xlsx"
stRow = 1
    With ActiveSheet
        endRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For c = stRow To endRow
                endCol = .Cells(c, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    If endCol > 1 Then
                        .Cells(c, endCol + 1) = fileName
                    End If
            Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution tests for activity using Counta and uses each active row's last column to use the activeworkbook's fullname.

```
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngLastCol As Long
Dim lngCounter As Long

lngLastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lngLastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

For lngCounter = 1 To lngLastRow
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(lngCounter, 1), Cells(lngCounter, lngLastCol))) > 0 Then
        Cells(lngCounter, lngLastCol + 1).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    End If
Next lngCounter
```